# HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: mule, esb

I am trying to connect to MS Dynamics 2013 REST Service and I needed to do NTLM authentication. I am able to do this thru a Java Class as below code snippet using Apache HTTP Client

```
NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("xxx", "yyy", "", "xyz.com");
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
```

As you can see I have to pass the username, password and domain to successfully connect. I am trying to do this thru Mule flow as below with no success. I am not sure where to pass the domain I tried it by passing thru userid attribute username@domain.com but throws a message failed to route I tried domain\username which doesn't even compile

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector"     doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true"   >
    <spring:property name="proxyNtlmAuthentication" value="true"/>
</http:connector>
<flow name="dynamicscrmFlow1" doc:name="dynamicscrmFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="5282" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <not-filter doc:name="Not">
            <http:request-wildcard-filter pattern="*.ico"/>
        </not-filter>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="http request #[message.payload]"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET"       doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json" connector-ref="httpConnector" port="80" host="abcd.com" path="abcde/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet" password="yyy" user="xxx">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `proxyNtlmAuthentication="true"` on your HTTP connector configuration?

Comment: I did Dave as you can see in the http connector reference

Comment: Why with a Spring property? Why not with an attribute?

Comment: I added to the connector reference as below still access denied<http:connector name="httpConnector"     doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true"  proxyNtlmAuthentication="true" >

Comment: :( Maybe give this connector https://github.com/mulesoft/http-ntlm-connector a try?